# rails undefined method `each' for #<Field

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form that allows user to register for a tournament.  In the process of building the registration form I hae dynamic nested fields with so far field_type of basic. When I load the participants new form I am trying to load all the fields from the Fields table with field_type  of basic.  It will find them and if I just try <%= @basic.name %> from the new form it will give the name of the last field in the database with that field_type, but if I try:

```
<% @basic.each do |b| %>
  <%= b.name %>
<% end
```

I get the error undefined method `each' for #<Field.

Here is the new action from the participants_controller:

```
def new
    @participant = @event.participants.new
    @user = User.find(current_user.id)
    @children = @user.children
    @basic = Field.find_by(event_id: @event.id, field_type: 'basic')
  end
```

Fields belong to events but do I have to connect them to participants to make this work?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`find_by`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find_by) only returns a single record (or `nil` if the criteria aren't matched) use [`where`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-where) to return a collection.

```
@basic = Field.where(event_id: @event.id, field_type: 'basic')
```

However assuming you have the association `has_many :fields` defined in `Event` you could also use:

```
@basic = @event.fields.where(field_type: 'basic')
```

And if you have the `scope :basic, -> { where(field_type: 'basic') }` defined in `Field` you can further simplify to:

```
@basic = @event.fields.basic
```